# #1111 - Invalid use of group function. I can't seem to understand what's wrong

Tags: mysql

I get the error:

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function.

I can't seem to understand what's wrong. My code is below:

```
Select * from (Select MAX(ticket_comment_date)
from ticket_movement_tran` group by ticket_id) AS T
where DATE(MAX(ticket_comment_date)) 
between DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '01-01-2014',  '%d-%m-%Y' ) ,  '%y-%m-%d' )
and DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '01-11-2014',  '%d-%m-%Y' ) ,  '%y-%m-%d' );
```

Comment: Use proper dates - the kind MySQL understands. Once you've figured that bit out, get back to us with proper DDLs and a desired result (and/or an SQLfiddle)

Comment: i am using xampp and these dates seem to work fine in other queries my point being even this is not working                                                         `Select * from (Select MAX(ticket_comment_date),ticket_id
from 'ticket_movement_tran' group by ticket_id) AS T
where ticket_id<'10';`

Comment: The query is nonsensical, hence my request for proper DDLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**issue**

`ticket_id` ( which is being grouped by in the inner query ) is not included in the selected fields. You can't group by a field which is not selected, hence the error message..

**fix**

> - add `ticket_id` to fields selected
> - no need for two layers of sql, can do this in one layer; adding the date filter logic in the having clause ( as it relates to the aggregated value )

**adjusted query**

```
select ticket_id, MAX(ticket_comment_date) 
from ticket_movement_tran 
group by ticket_id
having DATE(MAX(ticket_comment_date)) between
DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '01-01-2014', '%d-%m-%Y' ) , '%y-%m-%d' ) 
and DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( '01-11-2014', '%d-%m-%Y' ) , '%y-%m-%d')
;
```

**notes**

I assume since you are using DATE(MAX(ticket_comment_date)) that ticket_comment_date is not properly defined as a date. Would recommend changing the storage type for this field to a DATE..

So if the ticket_comment_date is currently a character field, then `MAX(ticket_comment_date)` can give you a different results than you expect. in particular lexical ordering ( ordering of character fields ) can differ from numerical or date based ordering

Comment: I see no improvement here

Comment: @Ali nw - just be careful about the ordering over character fields ( as per the last part of the answer )